# Selenium WebDriver – How To Automate DatePicker on this complex site?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I'll glad for your assistance in automating datepicker in this website
[https://www.selina.com/](https://www.selina.com)
currently I not able to find a solution how to implement the automation correctly as in this web I don't have id's and I will be happy to have you advice on it.

Thanks

Comment: post your code and error log trace so we can solve your question. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Use `XPath` if there is no `ID`. you can try with `Selenium IDE` and get the `XPath`